Angle wrapping error (mishandling 0, pi, -pi)
I am trying to wrap the angle to be within the range of [-pi, pi]. I have tried many variations of the following code, it should be a very easy task, however, if the angle is already pi, -pi, or 0, it outputs it as negative (so pi = -pi, -pi = pi, 0 = -0).
Here is the code I currently have:
static double wrapAngle( double angle){
    while (angle < -M_PI) {
        angle += 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
    while (angle > M_PI) {
        angle -= 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
    return angle;
}

It correctly wraps everything except -M_PI, M_PI, and 0. It gives me the negative.

Why should it wrap -M_PI, M_PI and 0? Your loops checks less than -M_PI and greater than M_PI.

Please post a [mre].

"if the angle is already pi, -pi, or 0, it outputs it as negative (so pi = -pi, -pi = pi, 0 = -0)." - I don't see how that can happen if you use M_PI consistently (because your conditions check if the angle is less than -M_PI, or more than M_PI). Please post a [mre] (maybe you test with angle which is not exactly M_PI / -M_PI ?).

Another issue is that if the angle is very large or very small, inaccuracies due to floating point calculations will accumulate in your loops.

You could use a combination of std::fmod to clamp between 0 and 2pi first. So you don't get the issue @wohlstad describes.

It behaves correctly just as expected here on MSVC 17.1 and Intel ICX compilers. Need to know what compiler and settings the OP is using. Very slight rounding errors could swap pi and -pi since they describe the same angle +/- machine_eps. Harder to explain how 0 gets affected - there must be some other code elsewhere mangling that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

what if angle is 4*PI? Your function is flipping signs , e.g. 1.5 Pi would become -0.5 Pi, would matter for sin\tan and quaternion operations. normally one would use fmod or  analogous integer-precision function.

On "normal" hardware there is no -0. If there is, whole CORDIC will have a field day

@swift Depends what you mean by normal hardware. I have  in the past programmed machines with just one unsigned zero but anything that obeys today's IEEE754 FP standard must provide a signed zero +0 and -0 (although they still compare as equal but for example in division 1/0 then they send the result off to opposite infinities).

Your code increments by 2pi while it's less than -pi and decrements by 2pi while it's greater than pi. Normally one would expect it to repeatedly converge into the interval of [-pi, pi] with steps of +-2pi.
Yet, you observed that the results seem to be correct in their amplitude, but not in their sign. Think about it this way: if you already have 0, even then it inverts the sign, while your algorithm evidently does not change it.
Therefore you have a bug somewhere else, in a part of your code that you did not share here and that inverts the sign, whereas your algorithm looks mostly good, the only worry is a cumulative rounding error, which can be helped by doing a single computation (first finding out how many periods it's off by using a division, then multiplying the said number of periods by +-2pi) rather than moving by steps of +-2pi.
